# TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'innerHTML')

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
export const GenerateShop = () => {
    const shop = document.getElementById('shop')

    return (shop.innerHTML`
    <div className='product'>
    <img src={image} alt="ProductImage" className="product__image" />


    <div className="product__info">
        <p>{title}</p>
        <p className="product__price">
            <small>$</small>
            <strong>{price}</strong>
        </p>
        <div className="product__rating">
          {Array(rating).fill().map((_, i) => ( <p>⭐️</p> ))}
        </div>
    </div>

    <button >Add to Cart</button>
  </div>
    `)
}
```

i want to display the products inside the shop element

Comment: Your code is running at a point in time when the "shop" element is not in the DOM.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you're trying to generate a product display using a function named GenerateShop, which dynamically generates the HTML for each product and attempts to append it to an element with the id 'shop'. However, there are a few issues with your code snippet:

1. You're using a template literal incorrectly. To interpolate JSX inside a template literal, you should wrap it within curly braces {}.
2. It's better to use the dangerouslySetInnerHTML property in React to insert raw HTML content, but be cautious as it can lead to security vulnerabilities if not handled properly.
3. It's not recommended to manipulate the DOM directly in React. Instead, you should create components that represent your UI and let React manage the rendering.

Here's how you could structure your code more effectively using React components:

GenerateShop.js

```
const Product = ({ image, title, price, rating }) => (
  <div className='product'>
    <img src={image} alt="ProductImage" className="product__image" />

    <div className="product__info">
        <p>{title}</p>
        <p className="product__price">
            <small>$</small>
            <strong>{price}</strong>
        </p>
        <div className="product__rating">
          {Array(rating).fill().map((_, i) => ( <p key={i}>⭐️</p> ))}
        </div>
    </div>

    <button>Add to Cart</button>
  </div>
);

const GenerateShop = ({ products }) => (
  <div id='shop'>
    {products.map((product, index) => (
      <Product
        key={index}
        image={product.image}
        title={product.title}
        price={product.price}
        rating={product.rating}
      />
    ))}
  </div>
);

export default GenerateShop;
```

Then do this in your App.js component:

```
import React from 'react';
  import GenerateShop from './GenerateShop';
    
    const products = [
      // ... your product data here
    ];
    
    const App = () => {
      return (
        <div>
          <h1>My Shop</h1>
          <GenerateShop products={products} />
        </div>
      );
    };
    
    export default App;
```